# Edit ingredient in Recipes Project

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

[image]
This is a project in order to display the recipes and perform many operations on them such as deleting, adding and modifying, but when doing the amendment process, I want the modification icon to appear on the "component" like the deletion icon. It appears above the "component".
Where it is noticed in the picture that the modification icon appears on the side of the icon, and not on it, and I want the icon to appear on it.
How to solve this Problem?

In this file you have created the form in which the "component" will be modified.
EditIngredient.vue

```
<template>
  <v-row justify="center">
    <v-dialog v-model="editDialog" persistent max-width="1050px" height="400px">
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-btn
          fab
          accent
          class="grey lighten-1 margin"
          dark
          v-bind="attrs"
          v-on="on"
        >
          <v-icon>
            mdi-pencil
          </v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </template>
      <v-card>
        <v-layout>
          <v-flex xs12>
            <v-card-title class="color">
              <span class="headline"> Edit Ingredient</span>
            </v-card-title>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
        <v-divider xs12></v-divider>
        <v-layout>
          <v-flex xs12>
            <v-card-text>
              <v-container>
                <v-row>
                  <v-col cols="12">
                    <v-text-field
                      name="ingredientsQuantity"
                      label="IngredientsQuantity"
                      id="ingredientsQuantity"
                      v-model="editedIngredientsQuantity"
                      multi-line
                      required
                    ></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
              </v-container>
            </v-card-text>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
        <v-divider></v-divider>
        <v-layout>
          <v-flex xs12>
            <v-card-actions>

              <v-btn
                class="green--text darken-1"
                text
                @click="editDialog = false"
              >
                Close
              </v-btn>
              <v-btn class="green--text darken-1" text @click="onSaveChanges">
                Save
              </v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-row>
</template>
<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'
export default {
  props: ['ingredient'],
  data() {
    return {
      editedIngredientsQuantity: this.ingredient.ingredientsQuantity

    };
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions([
      'updateRecipeData'
    ]),
    onSaveChanges() {
      this.editDialog = false;    
      const stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(
        this.$store.dispatch('updateRecipeData', {
          id: this.ingredient.id,
          ingredientsQuantity: this.editedIngredientsQuantity
        })
      );
      // console.log("S: ", stringifiedData);
      localStorage.setItem("updateRecipe", stringifiedData);
      console.log(
        "We got : ",
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("updateRecipe"))
      );
    },
  },
};
</script>    
<style scoped>
.color {
  color: green;
  font-size: 2px;
}
.margin {
  margin-left: 1000px;
}
</style>
```

And here I called the mod component through:

```
           <app-edit-ingredient-details :ingredient="ingredient"> </app-edit-ingredient-details>
```

shoppingList.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-container class="mb-30">
      <v-flex class="floating-right">
        <v-btn
          large
          router
          to="/CreateNewIngrediets"
          class="green darken-1  btn-style margine mr-50"
        >
          <v-icon class="green darken-1 btn-style">mdi-plus</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-flex>
      <v-container>
        <v-layout
          row
          wrap
          v-for="ingredient in ingredients"
          :key="ingredient.id"
          class="mb-3 mt-4"
        >  
          <v-flex xs6 sm8 md4 offset-sm1 offset-md2>
            <v-card class="grey lighten-4 pl-3 ">
              <v-container fluid>
                <v-layout row class="pl-14">
                  <v-flex xs7 sm8 md9>
                    <v-card-title primary-title>
                      <v-flex xs7 sm8 md9>
                        <div>
                          {{ ingredient.Name }}
                        </div>
                      </v-flex>
                      <v-flex xs7 sm8 md9>
                        <div>
                          {{ ingredient.Quantity }}
                        </div>
                      </v-flex>
                      <v-flex xs5 sm4 md2>
                       <template v-if="true">
                                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <app-edit-ingredient-details :ingredient="ingredient"> </app-edit-ingredient-details>                        
                          </template>
                        <v-btn class="deleteColorIcon">
                          <v-icon
                            left
                            class=" pl-4"
                            @click="
                              $store.commit('delete_ingredient', ingredient.id)"
                          >
                            mdi-delete
                          </v-icon>
                        </v-btn>             
                      </v-flex>
                    </v-card-title>
                  </v-flex>
                </v-layout>
              </v-container>
            </v-card>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default {
  props:['ingredientData','recipeData'],
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'loadedRecipes',
      'loadedingredients'
    ]),
    Recipes() {
      const recipes =  this.loadedRecipe(this.recipeData);
       console.log('shopping List: ', recipes);
        return recipes
    },
    ingredients() {
      const ingredient =  this.loadedingredients;
      console.log('ingredient/Component: ', ingredient);
      return ingredient 
    }            
  }
};
</script>    
<style scoped>
.color {
  color: #43a047;
}
.deleteColorIcon {
  color: #e53935;
}
.btn-style {
  color: aliceblue;
}
</style>
```

This file was used by the component in order to be used in another component.
main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import VueRoute from 'vue-router'
import { routes } from './router/index'
import { store} from './store'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import AlertCmp from './components/shared/alert.vue'
import EditRecipeDetails from './components/Recipes/Edit/EditRecipeDetails.vue'
import EditIngredientDetails from './components/shoppingList/Edit/EditIngrediet.vue'    
Vue.config.productionTip = false    
Vue.use(VueRoute)
Vue.use(Vuetify)
Vue.component('app-alert',AlertCmp)
Vue.component('app-edit-recipe-details',EditRecipeDetails)
Vue.component('app-edit-ingredient-details',EditIngredientDetails)    
const router = new VueRoute({
  routes,
  mode:'history'
})    
new Vue({
  vuetify,
  store,
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: Its very unclear what you need the code to do and how it fails to achieve that result

Comment: I want to edit the Quantity of the ingredient for example instead 5kg I edit it to 9kg but the icon is outside the ingredient "sugar"